How to copy style and formatting from a template chart to a new chart?
I'm working on a VBA project in Excel where I need to create multiple charts based on data in a worksheet. I have a template chart with specific formatting and styling that I want to apply to each new chart I create.
My goal is to copy the chart type, chart area formatting, plot area formatting, legend formatting, title formatting, and any other relevant styles from the template chart to the new charts I create dynamically.
Here's the relevant code I have so far:
Sub CreateCharts()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim templateChart As ChartObject
    Dim newChart As ChartObject
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set templateChart = ws.ChartObjects("TemplateChart")
    
    ' Code to create new charts based on data
    ' ...
    
    ' Attempt to copy formatting from template chart
    CopyChartFormatting templateChart.Chart, newChart.Chart
    
End Sub

Sub CopyChartFormatting(sourceChart As Chart, targetChart As Chart)
    ' Code to copy formatting properties from sourceChart to targetChart
    ' ...
End Sub

I'm struggling with writing the CopyChartFormatting sub procedure. I've tried accessing various properties of the Chart object, but I'm not sure which properties control the different aspects of the chart's formatting and style.
Can someone provide guidance or sample code on how to effectively copy the chart type, chart area formatting, plot area formatting, legend formatting, title formatting, and any other relevant styles from a template chart to a new chart using VBA in Excel?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any additional information or clarification.
The structure of the sheet its like this:

The Template Chart:

I tried accessing various properties of the Chart object, such as ChartType, ChartArea.Format, PlotArea.Format, Legend.Format, and ChartTitle.Format, to copy the formatting from the template chart to the new chart. I expected that by setting these properties on the new chart to match the corresponding properties of the template chart, the new chart would take on the same formatting and styles as the template.
However, when I ran the code, the new chart did not fully inherit the formatting from the template chart. While some properties like ChartType and basic formatting were applied correctly, other aspects like the chart area fill, plot area formatting, legend styling, and chart title formatting did not match the template chart.
It seems that there are additional properties or sub-properties that need to be set to fully replicate the template chart's formatting, but I'm unsure of which specific properties to target or how to access and set them correctly.


There are numerous format settings on the chart object, making it challenging to iterate through all the properties and copy them.

Solution:

Export the chart template as a .crtx file and then apply it to the new chart.

Microsoft documentation:

Chart.ApplyChartTemplate method (Excel)


Chart.SaveChartTemplate method (Excel)

Sub CopyChartFormatting(sourceChart As Chart, targetChart As Chart)
    Const SPATH = "\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\"
    Const CHART_TPL = "ChartTpl.crtx"
    Dim tplFile As String
    tplFile = Environ("APPDATA") & SPATH & CHART_TPL
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill tplFile
    On Error GoTo 0
    sourceChart.SaveChartTemplate tplFile
    targetChart.ApplyChartTemplate tplFile
End Sub

Sub Test()
    With ActiveSheet
    CopyChartFormatting .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart, .ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
    End With
End Sub


